# ng-materials md-select change style to look like bootstrap dropdown

Tags: css, angularjs, bootstrap-4, angularjs-material, md-select

I am using angularjs and ng-material in my project. I want to make md-select dropdown look like bootstrap dropdown. Attached the dropdown link for the Reference.. I have added animations and it working fine but the prob is when the dropdown is closing.. white backgorund is shown when the dropwdown is closing. Link is in comments. Any help will be helpful.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/MWKdgaZ

Comment: please add the relevant code sections also inside your question

Comment: @Daniel I have tried adding code.. but I was getting error.. that is why I have added the link.. Please check the link.. Thank you